# Изменение записи в sql через Ajax при нажатии кнопки

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Есть код которые выводит из SQl все данные. К каждой строке есть кнопка "скрыть" чтобы скрывать каждую строку отдельно. Теперь нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, отправлялся запрос в sql на изменение записи в колонке  на 0. Сделать запрос через Ajax.

```
<?php
    while ( ( $name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1) ) )
      {
     
       echo "<p  id=h{$name['ID']}>". $name['ID']. ' '. $name['PRODUCT_ID']. ' '.$name['PRODUCT_PRICE']. ' '. $name['PRODUCT_ARTICLE']. ' '.$name['PRODUCT_QUANTITY']. ' '.$name['DATE_CREATE']. 
       "<button onclick=\"mytoggle('{$name['ID']}')\">Скрыть</button> </p>";
     }
    ?>
     
    <script>
    function mytoggle(num) {$("#h" + num).toggle();};
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

если правильно понял Вам то нужно создать отдельный файл например ajax.php
написать ajax запрос

```
    function mytoggle(num) {
$("#h" + num).toggle();

    $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax.php',         /* Куда пойдет запрос */
    method: 'get',             /* Метод передачи (post или get) */
    dataType: 'json',          /* Тип данных в ответе (xml, json, script, html). */
    data: {id: num},     /* Параметры передаваемые в запросе. */
    success: function(data){   /* функция которая будет выполнена после успешного запроса.  */
        alert(data);            /* В переменной data содержится ответ от ajax.php. */
    }
});
}
```

php file

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE myTable SET Visible='0' WHERE id=$id";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Да все получилось. Спасибо. И такой вопрос, мне еще нужно сделать динамически изменяемые цифры (также из бд вытаскивается количество а мне вот нужно при помощи + и - менять их и чтобы все сохранялось в бд). Может посоветуете что-нибудь. Мне также нужно будет сделать на js на первый взгляд. И еще раз спасибо

Comment: не много не понял можно подобно?

Comment: Может вы знаете хороший учебник или видео гайды про js?